# No puedo graficar el "color key" al hacer un Heatmap en R

Tags: r, rstudio, map, ggplot2, revisión-de-código

Hice un heatmap en R Studio y no consigo hacer que el grafico de color (color key) aparezca, lo he intentado con la librería de viridis y viridisLite y no consigo hacer que se muestre cuando grafico mis datos, el código es el siguiente:

```
> five <- read.csv("heatmap.csv", check.names = FALSE, header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
> lm5 <- data.matrix (five)
> heatmap(lm5, main = "Nivel de Mosaicismo", scale = 'column', margins = c(4,4), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, col = coul, cexRow = 0.9)+
viridisLite::viridis()
```

A continuación adjunto mi set de datos por cualquier duda:

```
Indiv CromW CromZ
13 0.012648149 0.552643989
14 0.105132075 0.390646103
15 0.041738482 0.018658899
16 0.117558557 0.409633285
17 0.091240041 0.185527785
18 0.046507116 0.210125853
19 0.037598203 0.429750122
20 0.10712214 0.186738606
21 0.217709562 0.283448316
22 0.09379019 0.194742981
23 0.043701659 0.102053152
24 0.074641537 0.469280123
25 0.341867179 0.206897827
26 0.057166766 0.279050462
27 0.016835687 0.541384976
28 0.116121799 0.040174392
32 0.075026719 0.113470555
33 0.228849041 0.462432425
34 0.020023541 0.338603644
35 0.0527578 0.093316563
36 0.146853027 0.283502459
37 0.064289486 0.394752917
38 0.032486672 0.171375757
39 1 0.211895903
40 0.001175978 0.303468261
41 0.230911771 0.077961641
42 0.031045694 0.278706386
43 0.217599034 0.43520242
44 0 0.292784263
45 0.038336003 0.637316949
46 0.074757266 0.185450483
```

> `Cita en bloque`

Comment: Bienvenida Nancy Trujillo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba si esto te funciona

```
five <- read.csv("heatmap.csv", check.names = FALSE, header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
lm5 <- data.matrix (five)
heatmap(lm5, main = "Nivel de Mosaicismo", scale = 'column', margins = c(4,4), Colv = NA, Rowv = NA, col = viridis(50), cexRow = 0.9)
```

A mi me genera el heatmap con el color virdis como estas buscando, como otra nota, si eliminas  `check.names = FALSE, header = TRUE, row.names = 1` tambien genera la columna de Individuos.